# Pattern to Implement an OO interface to a C program written in an imperative style

Tags: c++, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

Imagine a legacy C program written in an imperative style: top-down, no objects, and peppered with `goto` statements. This program implements a dependent in an observer pattern; i.e., the subscriber in a pub-sub architecture.

The task is to implement an OO interface to said program.

What design pattern fits best here? At first, I jumped to an `Adapter` pattern:

**Adapter**

> Convert the interface of a class into another interface clients
>   expect. Adapter lets classes work together that couldn't otherwise
>   because of incompatible interfaces [Go4, 8]

The problem here is that an adapter converts the interface of another **class**. in this case, there is no class to convert; C doesn't have classes.

Next I thought `proxy`:

**Proxy**

> Provide a surrogate or placeholder for another object to control
>   access to it. [Go4, 9]

This fits--sort of--but doesn't seem to capture the essence of what I'm trying to do.

**Facade**

> Provide a unified interface to a set of interfaces in a subsystem.
>   Facade defines a higher-elevel interface that makes the subsystem
>   easier to use. [Go4, 9]

Perhaps... This may be the best option, but I'm not sure.

Which design pattern is most applicable in this scenario? Thx, Keith :^)

Comment: Facade all the way. That's how JNA in java does it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access

Comment: Do you need a pattern at all?

Comment: What is with this obsession with patterns? Just write code which makes sense for you, is maintainable and get's the job done.

Comment: Are you sure you _need_ an OO interface?

Comment: @SergeyA "Makes sense to you" doesn't necessarily mean it makes sense to the next guy.

Comment: It's an opinion question, but a good one, so I wouldn't have downvoted. I would probably think of it like an adaptor, but really you're just making an interface. (Facade is something you put in front of several slightly different things, I believe.)

Comment: I respectfully disagree that this is an "opinion question." There is a **correct** answer here: the right pattern to use in this situation. Pattern questions require a little more thought; just because it's not as simple as how to print ``hello world`` to the screen doesn't make it an opinion question. ;(

Comment: "he right pattern to use in this situation" - which pattern (if any) is "right" is definitely an opinion.

Comment: No... sturcotte06's answer was on-point. Facade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patterns make it easier for you to explain what you are doing to somebody else, who is already familiar with the same patterns; they do not automatically make your job easier.

In your situation it does not appear to be a need for any pattern at all: you are writing C++ classes to define an interface for a pub-sub system, and call C functions inside member functions implementing the interface. This is basic encapsulation: users of your C++ classes have no ides what's going on inside the implementation, while the implementation hides all the spaghetti/gotos from them.

You could potentially describe it as an application of the adapter pattern, even though all you have is a collection of C functions, not classes. At a very general level, non-OO functions could be thought of as class functions of a single top-level class; your "adapter" puts a set of classes on top of them as a C++ interface.

Comment: Great comment, thank you; you make some very good points.